# Magento Showing incorrect sales order report

Tags: magento-1.9, sales, reports, magento1.9.3.1

I am using Magento 1.9.3.1.

Magento is showing incorrect sales order report. Some orders are not considered into Magento sales order report.

I have total 5 orders on 13 June and in the report, it is showing only 3 and also the order total is also wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think order report shows orders which are not pending. means either processing state or shipped state(close).